# How to delay JavaScript function call using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, buttonclick

I have a couple of code snippets. Basically, I want to need that when a user clicks on the button the output which comes should be delay by 2-5second. more convenient if text come please wait... on clicking the button(but not in the button text). or "loading image" like preloader.

Any help/suggestion please

```js
function yes() {
  var button = document.getElementById('test');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<button onclick="yes()">Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a delay function `const delay = (dur) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, dur));` to get something like this:

```js
const delay = (dur) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, dur));

async function yes() {
  var button = document.getElementById('test');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Please wait a while ...";
  await delay(1000);
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<button onclick="yes()">Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

or a simple timeout `setTimeout(yes, 1000)`:

```js
function yes() {
  var button = document.getElementById('test');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  console.log("clicked on Test-Button");
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<button onclick="setTimeout(yes, 1000)">Test</button> <!-- timeout -->
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Please don't [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235). If a question has been answered before, flag it to be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: How Can I add please wait A while... text when the user click on button

Comment: See the edit on the first snippet!